# Logistics of a large data transfer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, raid, rsync

This is the setup:

I have a Ubuntu server that is doing the heavily lifting. Its pulls backups from an NFS and puts them on a Drobo device connected via USB using rsync. The Drobo has two seperate shares mounted on the Ubuntu machine at `/drobo` and `/drobo2`. Each share is made up of two 1TB scsi drives raided using the proprietary Drobo raid. I put daily backups on `/drobo` and it takes about 4 hours to do 800GB (mostly large .img files that are copied in full each time). This performance is decent, I guess.

The problem/wierdness:

Today I tried a backup that I would like to do monthly; moving the backups from `/drobo` to `/drobo2` for longer term backup. This rsync job had been going on for about 16 hours now! This is what I suspect. The data has to travel from the original share `drobo` to the server then from the server to the target share `drobo2`. Is this the case, and the explanation for the poor performance?

Comment: Are your backups individual files or partition/drive images? Are these static files or backups just taken? If backing up files, it's faster and easier to use the `--log` option for `rsync` since it logs all files and their hashes to a log file that's used for every backup; before `rsync` physically moves any files, it verifies their hashes against the log file and only when they don't match does `rsync` then copy over the file. This is the method and [script](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/TrueNAS/rsync-backup.sh) I use on my TrueNAS server to backup zpools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the moving takes so long because it moves from Drobo to server and then back to Drobo. I'd suggest you to merge two separate arrays at your drobo and then you'll be able to just move a file inside one share in just a moment.

Comment: I don't know a whole lot about this Drobo device. I was keeping the arrays to 2tb a piece, because it seems like you start running in to issues if you exceed that. Its Drobo Pro, I'm not sure the generation.

Comment: @dan08 Didn't knew about the possible issues with large arrays in Drobo, but it's not related. Your issue with long file moving can be solved by merging the shares.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm not understanding what you mean by "merging". Does that mean reformatting the array into one large 4tb share? What do you mean by merging?

Comment: @dan08 yes, I mean exactly that.